# Chat integration for mobile Apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application

Is there a Open source /Free Chat solution that can be integrated into the mobile app.

I am looking for a ready made solution rather than creating my own solution .

Comment: Are you looking for an open source server side FREE solution which you can host on your own or something like https://www.applozic.com which provides open source client SDKs but server hosting is not free?

Comment: This shouldn;t be closed. I need same help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XMPP Framework.Please refer the link below.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

This looks like great thingy. Take a look at their documentation :)